# Using LINQ Join Extension-Method on List & DataRowCollection

Tags: c#, linq, list, join, datatable

I'd like to `Join` a `List` and a `DataRowCollection`,

my Code so far looks like this:

```
attrList.Join<Attribute, DataRow, string, Attribute>(
    dt.Rows,
    attr => attr.Name,
    dataRow => dataRow[0].ToString(),
    (a, b) => new Attribute(a.Name, a.Value, b[1].ToString()));
```

attrList is a List of type MyProject.Attribute, which contains a string-Property "Name", the DataRowCollection comes from a DataTable (duh) and contains 2 Values, Index 0 contains a string that should match the Name-Property of Attribute (which is why I'm using join) and Index 1 contains a 2nd string-value which will be appended to the existing Attribute using an overloaded ctor.

Unfortunately, this does not work.

Error:

> [...]List<[...]> does not contain a definition for Join and the best extension method      overload [...] has some invalid arguments.

I simply can't find what's supposed to be wrong here.

Here's the Constructor of Attribute:

```
public Attribute(string name, string value, string control)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
    this.control = control;
}
```

Comment: Try changing the `Join` call to non-extension form to get a better error message: `Enumerable.Join<...>(attrList, dt.Rows, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTable.Rows is not generic i.e. it does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` so you can't use it in Linq, try below:

```
attrList.Join<Attribute, DataRow, string, Attribute>(
            dt.AsEnumerable(),
            attr => attr.Name,
            dataRow => dataRow[0].ToString(),
            (a, b) => new Attribute(a.Name, a.Value, b[1].ToString()));
```